# Rselenium web-scraping with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

For example, I want to scrape the data from this web-page(The Space,Amenities,Prices...and reviews
https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/9985824?guests=1&s=d2dNfFMd

I want to use for this purpose rselenium package.
This is my code:

```
url <- "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/9985824?guests=1&s=d2dNfFMd"
library('RSelenium')
pJS <- phantom()
library('XML')
shell.exec(paste0("C:\\Users\\Daniil\\Desktop\\R-language,Python\\file.bat"))
Sys.sleep(10)

checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName="chrome", port=4444)
remDr$open(silent=T)
```

and then with the help of SelectorGadget I found, I think, right elements for scraping:

```
var <- remDr$findElements('css selector','#details hr+ .row')
```

My question is: how can I bring it into the text(character strings)?
Or maybe exists other approach with rselenium for collecting data.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is in `file.bat` but it appears you are primarily interested in collecting data about the amenities of the listing. I just used firefox and skipped over the phantomjs parts of your code:

```
url <- "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/9985824?guests=1&s=d2dNfFMd"

library('RSelenium')

checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName="firefox", port=4444)
remDr$open(silent=T)
remDr$navigate(url)

var <- remDr$findElement('css selector','#details hr+ .row')

print(var$getElementText())
[[1]]
[1] "The Space\nAccommodates: 2\nBathrooms: 1.5\nBed type: Real Bed\nBedrooms: 1\nBeds: 1\nProperty type: Apartment\nRoom type: Private room\nHouse Rules"
```

From here you can parse the string or perform additional data collecting.